# Use different ID's ranges for dev and prod databases

Tags: database, architecture, integration, primary-key

I am working on web service with great amount of integration tasks. We connect our service with tens of other services each of which has its own persistent storages. Of course we have a few different environments for dev, stage and production purposes. Each of integrated services has at least two environments: dev and prod. I consider two approaches to reliably separate environments:

First one is to use **two different DBs** for dev and (stage + prod) circuits. Such approach allows to have only one ID's sequence per each domain object and therefor will be no one collision in third party services. Pros: simplicity. Cons: dangerous access from stage to prod DB.

Second one is to use **three different DBs** and reserved ranges for primary keys of objects used for integration (eg. user pk, order No, etc.). In such case we restrict access from unstable stage env only to stage DB and prevent any collisions by reserved ranges.

But idea of using reserved ranges or IDs seems strange to me. Any advices?

**UPD:** Let I clarify my situation in another way. For each third party service production environment I have two environment on my side: stage and production. Thus, if I have two different databases for my prod and stage envs without specified non-intersected ranges of IDs of objects that are transmitted from my side to third party service there will be collisions between my stage and prod environments on third party service side. Should I use one DB for stage and prod environments or introduce ranges of IDs?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have stage and prod in the same database?  I have always had three databases, dev, stage, and prod, all with an ID sequence per domain object.

This keeps stage and prod physically separated.

If nothing else, how else do you allow new database changes to be verified in stage without applying them (untested) to prod?

Comment: I agree that in case of same DB behind stage and prod env there will be untested database changes on prod. You say that you have thee databases, all with an ID sequence per domain object. Does sequences are split by ranges or it is irrelevant in your case? Please, see at my question update.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand.  You are sending content to a third party system.  You do this from both prod and stage environment.  You want some way to distinguish on the other end between prod and stage content, and you would like to use a sequence range to do this with.

Comment: Do the ids you send to the third party system have to be numeric, single-field ids?  If not, I would try and make a composite id of some sort.  Have one field designating the environment, and one for the object id.  That way you could have dev, stage, prod, beta, qa, etc... Lots of different environments, and an easy filter to tell which content comes from which.  If they need a single field, but it can be alpha-numeric, use these environments as a prefix (prod-1234 is a different object than stage-1234).

Comment: If you really need a single, numeric key, you could use them as masks, but this seems incredibly risky, unless you put a large enough gap between them that they can NEVER overlap.  I guess this is ultimately ID ranges, although I would drive this as separate logic from the underlying database sequence if at all possible.  Make something fairly hard-coded, otherwise it's something you will always have to think about as you promote from dev to stage to prod.

Comment: Great idea to use string prefix of env for transferred IDs. Sadly not all services allow to use non-numeric ID. I use PostgreSQL as primary DB and last one provides flexible sequences functionality to organize ranges.

Comment: It sounds like you are stuck with ranges.  I still think you should separate stage & prod though.